# Correct way to Sign out a user programmatically

Tags: login, account

I'm working on an application which has custom admin pages in CMS and also the front-end website.
Both these have the `Sign-out` feature and this is the method being used to sign out the user.

`AuthenticationManager.Logout();`

This works, but is there anything else that needs to be done like deleting cookies etc.

Using Sitecore 10.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the Sitecore documentation, the `AuthenticationManager.Logout()` method does everything automatically.

When a user signs out from an external identity provider, Sitecore Identity redirects the user to the logout page of this identity provider, and then back to Sitecore. A full sign out from both Sitecore and the underlying identity provider usually cannot happen with a single request.

However, Sitecore Identity handles everything automatically when you use the `AuthenticationManager.Logout()` method.

You can refer to the document for more details.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/sitecore-experience-manager/understanding-sitecore-authentication-behavior-changes.html